# "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'" while reading a file line by line using StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I am following a tutorial online to read a simple text file line by line in c# but I get this error that I can't wrap my head around.

This is my simple code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("hello.txt");
```

but this gives me an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

[This article on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the same code and there it works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have your tried a clean and rebuild? The constructor with a string parameter is definitely valid. I'm assuming this error is at compile-time correct?

Comment: What framework do you use ?

Comment: @DanD hard to say without knowing the used framework, this constructor for example is not included in netStandard<2.0, also this is missing in netCore<2.0

Comment: I'm new to c#, where can I see which framework I use?

Comment: @d-j good point on different frameworks, In your project file *.csproj you should see a TargetFramework section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read a file the easiest way is

```
var path = "c:\\mypath\\to\\my\\file.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
var path = "c:\\mypath\\to\\my\\file.txt";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `foreach` then you should use `File.ReadLines()` to avoid having the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\hello.txt");
 while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     Console.WriteLine (line);
     counter++;
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: What's the use of `counter`? Plus, for a type that implements `IDisposable`, you should use the `using` pattern (or put your `file.Close()` in a `finally` block): see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects.